# Website needs to convert from http to https redirect

Tags: redirect, https

I am working on a website and I have secured it using an SSL Certificate. The Https: works when manually typed in https://www.example-direct.co.uk it shows no error and has a secure icon. However, if we enter example.co.uk it directs it to the http: without the secure key.

I am just wondering if I can do a simple redirect? This is the redirect we currently have set up in .htaccess. What do I add here to redirect to http: to Https://

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# Redirect non www. to www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example-direct\.co\.uk
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example-direct.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]

# Remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1? [R=301,L]

# Remove .php ONLY if requested directly
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (\.php)
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php /$1 [R=301,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php
```

Comment: My website is not in Wordpress, I simply need a fix so that if anyone enteres http://www.example-direct.co.uk it would redirect them to https://www.example-direct.co.uk